# How to figure out wether polymer element is loaded or not?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I want import elements dynamically with `Polymer.import( elements, callback )`. If elements is already imported, then callback never gets called, otherwise it is called when elements is loaded.

The question is: is there a standart way to figure out if polymer element is loaded or not?

Comment: If I understand the function correctly `callback` will always be called when all the scripts have finished loading. See if one of the scripts fails to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until you have an element registered, it’s treated as standard `HTMLElement`.

So, you might check elements in the following way:

```
<!-- IN HEAD: core-pages would be loaded -->
<link href="core-pages/core-pages.html" rel="import"> 
...

<!-- IN BODY: core-animated-pages would be NOT loaded -->
<core-pages id='reg'></core-pages>
<core-animated-pages id='unreg'></core-animated-pages>
...

<script>
  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
    /* will print false ⇒ registered */
    console.log(document.getElementById('reg').constructor === HTMLElement);
    /* will print true ⇒ unregistered */
    console.log(document.getElementById('unreg').constructor === HTMLElement);
  });
</script>
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/uqxn6RlBXZ3746AhTnON?p=preview